# "await HTTPClient.GetAsync" never completing

Tags: asp.net, async-await, .net-4.5.2

I had this code working in .Net Core. We realized Core wasn't the best fit for us right now, so I have been refactoring in .Net 4.5.2 and when I call

`HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(passedlURI);`

It just continues thinking indefinitely. I have pointed it at a local host version of my API and confirmed that the API is reading the header and returning my data correctly, I have used Postman to confirm that both the live API and localhost API are sending me the correct data. Here is my code so far:

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this Code compiles...Anyway!? Further this architecture doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Can you turn `public string CallAPI` into `public async Task<string> CallAPI`?

Comment: @DotNetDev You don't need a return statement in an `async Task` method. Only `async Task<T>`.

Comment: Right, it's void, thx

Comment: Why did you use three methods here? Looks like they can all be combined into one. And you don't need any fields, just use local variables.

Comment: @mason It's three different methods because eventually the RunAsync is going to have a switch in it based on an enumeration (Get, Post, Put, etc). The end goal is that we'll be able to call `APICall.CallAPI(URL, CallType.Post, User, Object)` and it will always return a JSON string that will be up to the caller to deserialize correctly.

Comment: I still don't see why you need to use fields. HttpClient implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). You need to dispose of it properly, and that's difficult when it's a field. None of those actually need to be fields. And you can accomplish what you just described with two methods instead of three.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure to use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` with each of your `await`. Waiting synchronously on a task that internally awaits on the current synchronization context is a well-known cause of deadlocks in ASP.NET.

For instance, instead of:

```
await GetAPIAsync();
```

Do:

```
await GetAPIAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Of course, it would be even better if you didn't wait synchronously on a task to begin with.

The issue does not happen on ASP.NET Core because it doesn't use a custom synchronization context.